# Understanding usage of two-way prepositions (Wechselpräpositionen) + Dative / Accusative

Tags: preposition, dative, accusative, wechselpraeposition

As a non-native speaker, I am unable to wrap my head around the usage of prepositions. Just today in class, my teacher asked the following question from a text in A2 Sprach Training book.

> Wer macht Parties in der Freizeit?

(We answered, "Ute".)

Now, my question here is, how is it that the two-way preposition *in* is used with the Dative here?

This is something which I learned in A1, that if the question answers to "Wo" we must use the preposition in Dative and if the question answers to "Wohin", we must use the preposition in Accusative. (Ich bin im Kino v.s. Ich gehe ins Kino). But the question being asked is neither "Wo" nor "Wohin" but *Wer*. Why is the preposition used as *in der* and not as *in die* ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When *in* is used to give a place or a time as answers to questions with *wann* or *wo* you must use the Dative. When it is used to give a direction (as in the answer to the question with *wohin*) it stands with Accusative.

In the question *Wer macht Parties in der Freizeit?* the expression *in der Freizeit* specifies the time, so the Dative is used.

Comment: Oh great! I thought because "Wer" is there, we used Dative. So, prepositions of time/place is dative and directions is accusative. Will this logic apply to every sentence? I don't want to make mistake while writing to my German colleagues, and I really want to start writing e-mails (at least with basic responses) so that I get better soon.

Comment: there are other prepositions than _in_ where other cases must be used, so although there are tendencies towards certain cases for those categories there are exceptions. The first thing I found is a list of German prepositions on the German Wikipedia (https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%A4position) there might be other better lists out there in the internet

Comment: Just out of curiosity, does a native speaker also make mistakes while speaking? I mean it is soo difficult to remember everything. I don't even know half of my native language, even though I have been speaking it since young age.

Comment: Yes, there are also German native speakers who make grammatical mistakes while speaking. Also, in everyday spoken language many people don't use complex grammatical constructions (and back to topic also not all the prepositions that are on this list)

Comment: I'd like to add that there are also time configurations that take in + acc... "Wir tanzen in den Mai." The point is that a direction is expressed by acc and a fixed point by dat. no matter whether time or place

Comment: "Auf ins nächste Jahrtausend" :-)

Comment: @Emanuel I didn't understand that example at all. Why is 'Mai' not in dative? How can time be a direction, even in figurative sense? And if there is a possibility of giving an answer to 'wann' in accusative, why make the rule in the first place? And could you please give me the traslation of the "tanzen" sentence; I am not able to wrap my mind around this concept.

Comment: ok so first of: noone makes rules. Rules in language are but a simplified description of what is. Then: the sentence means something like "We're dancing into Mai" for instance from the 30th of April. And then it is not answering "wann", it is somewhat answering "bis wann". And this is not so different to "bis wohin" which is a direction/destination. And why shouldn't there be a point in time as a destination. Sure, it's abstract but it makes sense to me. Another example would be "Wir feiern ins neue Jahr." or "Wir feiern in meinen Geburtstag rein." ... now what is birthday, anyway? Time? Place

Comment: all those words are indications of things or entities after or. Montag is an "entity" and so is "Park". One is local one is for time but what difference does it make for the grammar. If the noun(pronoun, noun replacing adverb) is used as a destination... accusative is probably more likely than dative.