# Rektion der Verben bei Präpositional-Ergänzungen: gibt's einen Weg zu bestimmen, ob man den Akkusativ oder Dativ benutzt?

Tags: preposition, grammatical-case, dative, accusative

In diesem Moment wiederhole ich die Präpositional-Ergänzungen:

> Verlass dich nicht auf dein Glück, sondern lern! --> sich verlassen auf + Akkusativ

> An den Kosten der Party haben sich alle Gäste beteiligt --> sich beteiligen an + Dativ

Diese beiden gehen mit dem Akkusativ, aber es gibt viele, die mit dem Dativ gehen.

Gibt es irgendwelches System, mit dem man bestimmen kann, was die richtige Rektion bei jedem Fall ist?  Oder hat man es nur aufwendig zu lernen?

Bei einigen, wie "vergleichen + Akkusativ + mit + Dativ" hat man nur eine einzige Möglichkeit

> Mandy vergleicht Münster mit ihrer Heimstadt York

weil hier man den Dativ mit "mit" benutzen muss.

Aber bei vielen Präpositional-Ergänzungen kommt es mir schwierig vor, zu sehen, ob es überhaupt eine Logik gibt.

Comment: Geht es um Wechselpräpositionen? [Hier](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6169/understanding-usage-of-two-way-prepositions-wechselpr%c3%a4positionen-dative-ac) ein Beispiel (englisch)

Comment: Danke.  Eigentlich nicht, aber es waren genau diese Wechselpräpositionen, die mich angereizt haben, bei den Präpositional-Ergänzungen auch irgendeine Art "System" zu finden.  D.h., bei den Wechselpräpositionen sprechen wir im Allgemeinen über "richtung" oder "Ort/Zeit", um zu entscheiden, ob wir den Akk. oder den Dat. benutzen.   Bei diesen Verb+Präposition Kominationen sehe ich keine ähnliche Unterscheidungssystem.  Dann muss man die halt auswendig lernen, was ich schaffen kann, aber irgend ein System wäre hilfreich.

Comment: Die Präpositionalobjekte mit *auf* stehen meines Wissens alle mit Akkusativ. Ich wüsste kein Gegenbeispiel.

Comment: @Janka Danke!  Es scheint, dass du Recht hast, zumindest dem Buch nach

Comment: Auch die mit *über* stehen alle mit Akkusativ. Die einzig Komplizierten sind die mit *an*. Da gibt es kein System.

Comment: "Bestehen auf" steht mit dem Dativ: "Sie bestand auf ihrem Recht".

Comment: Ich wüsste nicht, wie eine Regel, die alle derartigen Konstruktionen erfasst, überhaupt aussehen könnte. Im Fall von *auf* dürften aber die meisten Wendungen den Akkusativ benutzen, so dass man sich darauf beschränken könnte, die mit Dativ zu lernen, quasi als die Ausnahmen.

Comment: @HalvarF: War mir neu. Ich würde das auch mit Akkusativ benutzen. Z.B. *Ich bestehe auf die Bezahlung der Rechnung.* und nicht etwa *Ich bestehe auf der Bezahlung der Rechnung.* Letzteres klingt für mich einfach falsch.

Comment: @HalvarF: "beharren auf" ist vermutlich weniger diskutabel als "bestehen auf". Letzteres klingt in meinen Ohren sowohl mit dem Dativ wie auch mit dem Akkusativ richtig, ersteres klingt für mich mit dem Akkusativ falsch. Das liegt möglicherweise daran, daß der Akkusativ für eine Richtung steht, der Dativ aber für einen Ort. "beharren" kann man aber nur auf einem Ort, nicht in eine Richtung.

Comment: @bakunin Ja, "beharren" ist noch klarer. Die Argumentation mit dem Ort passt auch auf "bestehen", wenn auch nicht so deutlich.